# equals() method to check X and Y coordinates

Tags: java, line, coordinates, equals, point

Ok guys, first off sorry if this code is messy and if my equals() is completely wrong, but this is my first time using it.

I'm trying to create an equals method to check if two lines are equal, two lines are defined as equal if two end points are the same.

My first question is, am i even close with the method in the Point class, and also how would I call the equals() method in the Point class from the Line class?

Thanks for any and all help.

```
public class Point {

private int x;
private int y;

public Point( int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public String toString() {
    return "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!(o instanceof Point)) {
            return false;
        }
        return (x == ((Point) o).x && y == ((Point) o).y);
}
}
```

}

for the return this.y, it says "unreachable code". Also Should my Object be "Point" or "Line"?

```
public class Line {
private Point beg, end;
Color color;

public Line(Point beg, Point end, String color) {
    this.beg = beg;
    this.end = end;


public Point getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public Point getBeg() {
    return beg;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Beg=" + beg + ", End=" + end + ", Color" + color.toString();
}

Line() {
    return this.beg.equals(Point.x);
    return this.end.equals(Point.y);
}
```

}

I updated the equals() in point class but I'm still having trouble calling it from the Line class, would it be a similar fix?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You might have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655396/implementing-the-equals-method-in-java .

Comment: Check out this [how to override equals method article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unreachable code because you exited the method just before by `return`ing from it . You probably meant `this.x == ((Point)o).x && this.y == ((Point)o).y`.

You should have something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Point)) {
        return false;
    }
    return (x == ((Point) o).x && y == ((Point) o).y);
}
```

Also, for the `Line` class you compare the relevant fields (`beg` and `end`).

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Line)) {
        return false;
    }
    return (beg == ((Line) o).beg && end == ((Line) o).end);
}
```

When you override `equals` (and `hashCode`, always write them in pairs) it is a good idea to use the `@Override` annotation, in case you write `public boolean equals(Point o)` (notice the parameter is `Point`, not `Object`) by mistake, so the compiler will catch it.

Comment: Ok thanks this fixed my problem, but I'm still having trouble with the correct way to call it from the Line class?

Answer (score 0):

It says unreachable code since your equals() method will finish execution on `return this.x == ((Point)o).x;`

Try using:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this.x == ((Point)o).x && this.y == ((Point)o).y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this.x == ((Point)o).x && this.y == ((Point)o).y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public class Point {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (this.x == ((Point)o).x) && (this.y == ((Point)o).y);
    }
}
```

This way your code is not unreachable.

Also you must check:

```
if (!(o instanceof Point)) return false;
```

Comment: You should handle cases where `o` is `null`. All these answers should.

Comment: `null` is never an instanceof a class. So the instanceof check will handle `null` correctly. Checking for `null` explicitly is just a matter of style (and micro performance optimization).

Answer (score 0):

After the first `return` call the method exits so the second one is never evaluated.

Use `return (this.x == ((Point)o).x) && (this.y == ((Point)o).y);` instead.

```
public class Point {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o == null) return false;
        if(!(o instanceOf Point) return false;
        return (this.x == ((Point)o).x) && (this.y == ((Point)o).y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't ever have 2 return statements one after another, because the second one is always unreachable. You can use this instead, evaluating if `x` equals `o.x` and `y` equals `o.y`:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.x == ((Point)o).x && this.y == ((Point)o).y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'return' statement exits the method, which is why any code further down will never be reached. Also, it's good practice to check if the passed object is of the correct class, to avoid class cast exceptions:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Point) {
        Point po = (Point) o;
        return this.x == po.x && this.y == po.y;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The argument needs to be 'Object' and not 'Point' so this method overrides the Object.equals method

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
return this.x == ((Point)o).x;
return this.y == ((Point)o).y;
```

This code will return after checking for x but will never reach y.

So, in order to make your code work correctly use

```
return (this.x == ((Point)o).x)&&(this.y == ((Point)o).y);
```

This code will check for x and y both and then return

Answer (score 0):

If you override equals, you SHOULD/MUST override hashCode() also!

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if(o==this){return true;}
   if(!o instanceof Point){return false;}
   Point p = (Point)o;
   return (this.x==p.x && this.y==p.y);
}
```